# Regex: Matching two regular expressions

Tags: regex

Assume we have collection of strings as input:

```
str1: ABCD
str2: ABCD
str3: AWXYD
str4: AWXYD
```

The goal is to remove duplicates and preserve the unique ones. Having the above input, our output should look like the following:

```
ABCD
AWXYD
```

Unfortunately, the machine that produces this collection is error prone and sometimes misses some alphabets (see below). Luckily, we are able detect that there is a missing part. But we don’t know how large this missing part is. In reality we have the following input:

```
str1: A?CD
str2: AB?D
str3: AWXYD
str4: A?D
```

where `?` indicates the missing part.

In this example, we would like to preserve `A?CD` or `AB?D` and also `AWXYD`.

In an attempt to solve this, I substituted `?` with `.*` and assumed these strings to be regular expressions:

```
Reg1 --> A.*CD
Reg2 --> AB.*D
Reg3 --> AWXYD
Reg4 --> A.*D
```

Now I am trying to identify the duplicates by comparing regular expressions. Using this approach, one can easily match `Reg4` to `Reg3` because `Reg3` is actually a string (no missing part). Things become complicated when both have missing parts and therefore you have to compare regular expressions.

I wonder if it is possible or if there is a better solution for this.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**: Note that `str1` and `str2` might came from different strings (e.g. `AXCD` and `ABXD`). Our goal is to remove any (possible) duplicates and be sure that preserved strings are unique (even if we remove more). This is why we preserve either `str1` or `str2`. Thanks to Aaron who pointed this out.

**Edit 2**: There are millions of strings. That's why an algorithms is needed.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You seem to be looking whether regular expressions "intersect", rather than match : there are strings matched by Reg1 that are not matched by Reg2.

Comment: @Tomalak: Please see the edit for more information.

Comment: I understand even less after your edit. Where does the `AZYD` come from? What is hidden behind those `.*`? Ultimately, I don't understand how you plan to determine which patterns are errors and which are not. If the important point is string similarity, maybe the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) would help you better?

Comment: Interesting tip @Aaron. A quick look revealed [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966865/intersection-of-two-regular-expressions). Seems to be a solution but a slow one. I am curious to know if someone actually has a better plan for this. If not, I suggest you to put your reply as an answer.

Comment: Looking at the question you provided, I don't think the solutions provided are slow at runtime, and the solution based on the automaton library seems quick enough to implement. I'm not confident I've understood your problem so I won't post an answer, feel free to post your implementation as an answer

Comment: @Aaron: I tried to explain it further. Hope it helps. On the other hand, note that I have to do this for many collections where each collection contains millions of strings. That's why I am curious to see a faster solution. But if that's the only way, then tough luck. I have to implement a fast one.

Comment: You type a lot of text but it's unclear at all, so difficult to understand. Just make it clear please write something likes this. 1) what do you want to do? (put some sample input and expected output) 2) what have you tried? Please don't mix all of them up! that's just confused.

Comment: @terces907: Thanks for your comment! Hope it's more clear now.

Comment: Thanks for your updates, I understand it much better now. Another question though : `A?CD` and `AB?D` could correspond to two different data (i.e. `AXCD` and `ABYD`) so why decide to guess they're relative to the same data? Are you maybe sure to have some minimal number of duplicates?

Comment: Is it some kind of glob pattern matching? If yes, you should probably replace `?` by a single dot `.`, not `.*`.

Comment: @Aaron: Thanks man. Good point! I added another piece to cover these exceptions.

Comment: The rules are still not clear. Why are Reg1 and Reg2 possible candidates but not Reg4 versus all the others? I see that Reg1 and Reg2 matching is more reliable, but how should an algorithm decide? Is a minimum number of known matching characters required or a minimum percentage or something else?

Comment: @Olivier No. We don't know how large the missing part is. Therefore a `.*` is required.

Comment: The point of my question is: Why are Reg1 and Reg2 possible duplicates but not say Reg2 and Reg4? Because Reg4 is matching all the others. (I am not talking about the length of the missing parts but the length of the non-missing parts.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot: Indeed the `Reg4` is a possible candidate vs. all others. We want to detect duplicates. It doesn't matter in which comparison a candidate is selected as duplicate.

Comment: There are 3 possible result sets in this simple example: { "A?D" }, { "A?CD", "AWXYD" } and { "AB?D", "AWXYD" } and the number grows rapidly with increasing string collection sizes. Does it mind which set you are keeping at the end? If, by accident,  "A?D" happens to be the first string you encounter, then at the end only a single string will be left over.

Comment: Interesting point. Thanks @OlivierJacot. I would prefer to keep the ones with most information (i.e. `{"AB?D", "AWXYD"}` or `{"A?CD", "AWXYD"}`). But I understand that this procedure is order dependent. I have to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: I you have millions of strings, brute force algorithms won't work. If you take the naive approach of comparing each string to each other string (no matter how exactly this comparison is done), then you end up in `n*(n-1)/2` comparisons, i.e. **trillions of comparisons**!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think regular expressions is appropriate for such task. If you are asking if there is an *implemented* way to compare regular expressions, answer is NO. At least I haven't seen it. If you are asking if there is a way to implement it, I would say YES. You can represent regex as finite state machine as well as graph. And it is possible to check isomorphism of these things. But it would be enormously complex to do it for regular expressions. Three things that pops in my mind now is: [Levenshtein distance algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) , [Binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree) (extremely search efficient data structure) and [Black Board architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_system) . And also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5859561/getting-the-closest-string-match) you will find several answers that can help you. Good luck!

**P.S** PostgreSQL has `fuzzystrmatch` module with Levenshtein algorithm implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your pattern.

```
Reg1 --> A.*CD
```

and

```
Reg2 --> AB.*D
```

Sometimes, they are represented the same pattern e.g.

```
ABCD
```

Either `Reg1` or `Reg2` can be matched this text. That means there is some duplicated pattern inside `Reg1` and `Reg2`.

You might solve your problem by changing your pattern to

```
Reg1 --> A(?!B).*CD
// (?!B) means the second character can be any letters except `B`
```

and

```
Reg2 --> A.*(?<!C)D
// (?<!C) means the second last character can be any letters except `C`
```

Otherwise you can not distinguish between these two patterns.

Comment: Thanks @terces907. I am sorry but I can't see the relationship between your answer and my question. I understand where you are going. But that's not the point. Even if I rewrite the regular expressions the way you proposed, I still need to figure out how to compare them. That is the main question.

Comment: @Amin.A As I told you the problem is your patterns. Pattern suppose to be unique.

Comment: `A.*CD` and `AB.*D` can match the same text e.g. `ABCD`. That means your regexes are not good enough. You suppose to find the way to identify that what is the different between these two patterns. As I already suggested. You might do in a different way but just make them different.

Comment: Note that `intersect` of two regular expressions is not `null`, if there exists a string that both can match to (e.g. `ABCD`). @Aaron proposed to use this concept (i.e. detecting overlaps between regular expressions) to say if two strings are duplicates. We don't want to get rid of these overlaps. On the other hand, this is just a small example. It seems impractical to remove these overlaps for millions of strings.

Comment: Yes @Amin.A, What I try to tell you is get rid of intersect part or separate intersect part into a new pattern. There is no  choice.